# QT QFileDialog create unknown COM Object and security

Tags: c++, windows, qt, wmi

I need help for this issue. i want to uses WMI in my project, so that i can use WQL to get some data fom Windows OS.
Here is my code

```
QList<Drive> SystemDrive::getSystemDrive()
{
    QList<Drive> list;

    #ifdef _WIN64
    HRESULT hRes;
    hRes = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED );
    if(hRes == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)
    {
        //qDebug() << "Unable to launch COM: 0x" << QString::number(hRes, 16) << endl;
        //OleUninitialize();
        CoUninitialize();
        hRes = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
        if(FAILED(hRes))
        {
            qDebug() << "Unable to launch COM: 0x" << QString::number(hRes, 16);
        }
        //return 1;
    }
    qDebug() << "CoInitializeEx result 0x" << QString::number(hRes, 16);

    if((FAILED(hRes = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CONNECT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, 0))))
    {
        qDebug() << "Unable to initialize security: 0x" << QString::number(hRes, 16);
    }
    IWbemLocator* pLocator = NULL;
    if(FAILED(hRes = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pLocator))))
    {
        qDebug() << "Unable to create a WbemLocator: " << std::hex << hRes << endl;
        //return 1;
    }

    IWbemServices* pService = NULL;
    if(FAILED(hRes = pLocator->ConnectServer(L"root\\CIMV2", NULL, NULL, NULL, WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT, NULL, NULL, &pService)))
    {
        pLocator->Release();
        qDebug() << "Unable to connect to \"CIMV2\": " << std::hex << hRes << endl;
        //return 1;
    }

    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    if(FAILED(hRes = pService->ExecQuery(L"WQL", L"SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk", WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY, NULL, &pEnumerator)))
    {
        pLocator->Release();
        pService->Release();
        qDebug() << "Unable to retrive Logical Disk: " << QString::number(hRes, 16) << endl;
        //return 1;
    }

    IWbemClassObject* clsObj = NULL;
    int numElems;
    while((hRes = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &clsObj, (ULONG*)&numElems)) != WBEM_S_FALSE)
    {
        if(FAILED(hRes))
        break;

        Drive *tmpDrive;

        VARIANT vRet;
        VariantInit(&vRet);
        if(SUCCEEDED(clsObj->Get(L"Caption", 0, &vRet, NULL, NULL)) && vRet.vt == VT_BSTR)
        {
            tmpDrive = new Drive(QString((QChar*) vRet.bstrVal, SysStringLen(vRet.bstrVal)));
            tmpDrive->setType(Drive::DRIVE_TYPE::DRIVE_LOGICAL);
            VariantClear(&vRet);
        }
        VariantInit(&vRet);
        if(SUCCEEDED(clsObj->Get(L"DeviceID", 0, &vRet, NULL, NULL)) && vRet.vt == VT_BSTR)
        {
            QString id = "\\\\.\\";

            id.append(QString((QChar*) vRet.bstrVal, SysStringLen(vRet.bstrVal)));
            tmpDrive->setId(id);
            VariantClear(&vRet);
        }

        clsObj->Release();
        list.append(*tmpDrive);
    }

     pEnumerator->Release();
     pService->Release();
     pLocator->Release();
     CoUninitialize();
#endif

     return list;
}
```

that code run perfectly every time i call it. I can get what i need (List of Logical drive). The problem is when i call `QFileDialog` object and then call that function, that code will not work. I get error for `coInitializeSecurity` with error `RPC_E_TOO_LATE` and as result my `ExecQuery` will fail with error code `0x80041003` (WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED).

I think `QFileDialog` create COM object because there is mesage output in `Aplication Output Tab` (stdout) when I call `QFileDialog` object.

```
CoCreateInstance failed ()
CoCreateInstance failed ()
```

If I Call `QFileDialog` object first before that function, these message will not occur, and that function still not work. I need that function run normally without any interuption from any COM objects.

My questions :

1. Are there any way to detect what COM object that created by QT?
2. How can I know which security that initialized (CoInitializeSecurity) by QT?

**EDITED**
After read answers from [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) and [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8666197/daniel-s%C4%99k), I change my code. So I put `CoInitializeEx` in first time my app running with `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED`, after that I initialize `CoInitializeSecurity`, and then erase all `CoInitializeEx`, `CoInitializeSecurity`, and 'CoUninitialize' in that function. It works, i can call that function after opening `QFileDialog`.

Now,

3. Where should I call 'CoUninitialize'? should I call it before my app closed?
4. how can I assure that all COM interfaces that I have created (`WMI` and `QFileDialog`) destroyed properly? asume that I release all interface and enumeration from WMI like in my code, and for `QFileDialog` I call it in stack memory.

Comment: `QFileDialog` use to use system's (Windows) file dialogs. Probably this native dialog has COM components. For the sake of experiment try to use `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` option to see whether it still fails.

Comment: This goes off the rails early, the CoInitializeEx() calls are fundamentally wrong.  And yes, it screws up QFileDialog badly because it always requires COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED.  Or to put it another way, it always needs to be used on the UI thread.  Only the code that initialized the thread can determine the proper value for CoInitializeEx.  Apartment for any thread that pumps a message loop, generally only ever the app's main thread.  Multi-threaded for any worker thread.  Displaying shell dialogs on a worker thread is not possible.

Comment: @vahancho thank you for your reply. I have try it before, and stil fail.

Comment: CoUninitialize call just before leaving your outermost function. For all objects remember to destroy it when it is no longer needed. It would be good idea, for writing simple wrapper classes for automatic management (RAII).

Comment: @Daniel thank you. it is done. I put `CoUninitialize` before my app clossed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CoInitializeSecurity` should be called only **once** for a process. `RPC_E_TOO_LATE` means that it has already been called. Move call earlier, probably into initialization section of your process.